# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'WidePanel'

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

Hi I am running the following simple OLS:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm


df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,40,50], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": 
[32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})
result = sm.ols(formula="A ~ B + C", data=df).fit()
```

Unfortunately, it is throwing the following error: 
module 'pandas' has no attribute 'WidePanel'

Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Comment: What version of statsmodels and pandas are you using?

Comment: @coldspeed Panda : 0.24.2 and statsmodel: 0.8.0

Comment: I see... this works on statsmodels 0.9.0, try upgrading?

Comment: @coldspeed thank you very much! it was a version issue!